# React useState clarification needed. setState of a cart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Hi I got cat to work but need clarification on this or maybe even better way of doing things in the future.

So I have my cart

```
{
products: array(),
total_price: int()
}
```

cart is stored in cartContext and in localStorage.

Then I have all kind of methods to manipulate but there is one thing I don't get.

**Delete from cart**
First method of creating new cart w/o clicked item

```
export const deleteFromCart = (existingCart, productDatabaseId) => {
  let newProducts = existingCart.products.filter((obj) => {
    return obj.databaseId !== productDatabaseId;
  });
  existingCart.products = newProducts;
  existingCart = calculateTotalPrice(existingCart);
  localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(existingCart));

  return existingCart;
};
```

Then handler

```
  const [cart, setCart] = useContext(CartContext);
  const handleDeleteFromCart = (databaseId) => {
    let existingCart = localStorage.getItem("cart");
    if (process.browser) {
      existingCart = JSON.parse(existingCart);
      let updatedCart = deleteFromCart(existingCart, databaseId);

      setCart(updatedCart);
    }
  };
```

Questions:

1. As you can see I'm creating whole new cart everytime when doing changes. I think it's clean solution as long as CartProvider is stateless with hooks. Am I right?
2. I'm getting exisistingCart from local storage but I tried to use just state object for that manner

```
  const [cart, setCart] = useContext(CartContext);
  const handleDeleteFromCart = (databaseId) => {

    if (process.browser) {
      let existingCart = cart;
      let updatedCart = deleteFromCart(existingCart, databaseId);

      setCart(updatedCart);
    }
  };
```

In this case state won't refresh. setCart is setting previous version of the cart or not setting it at all. State doesn't change, only local storage cart is changing so after refresh (hook on loading cart from local storage) cart is proper(w/o clicked item) but it's not realtime. Why? My guess is that deleteFromCart method takes to loong to execute and setCart is executed before hand?

Need some clariffication on this.

Answer (score 1):

> My guess is that deleteFromCart method takes to loong to execute and setCart is executed before hand?

No this is not the case.

The `useState` will bail out of the render (aka. you do not see the changes until the next render and if there is no next render, as in your case, the old data is still shown), if the previous and current value in the state are the same, shallowly (`current === next`).

So if the `cart` that you put into the state is the same as previously, you do not see the change.

And that is what you are doing. `existingCart` is `cart` and you mutate this. Afterwards, you are setting the state to `cart` again, so the previous and current objects are the same, but mutated and react will skip the render.

The first code works, because you are creating a new object from the local state every time, so the `current !== next`.

What you need to do is to create a new `cart` object that you change: `let existingCart = {...cart};`

So in short, never mutate your state, but instead create a new object to safe the changes to.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Funny thing is that I know that but as always forgot. Upvote voted, but not shown. Thanks again.